# Unformatted content Ckeditor and rails issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

i am using ckeditor for my rails app. After i save the page, it shows  the unformatted content,

```
<p> <strong>test</strong></p> <h3 style="color:blue;"> <strong>test 1</strong></h3>
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: its not good practise to have styling in html try to do it in css.

Comment: how to in css ? isnt ckeditor handling that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using rails 3.x. try this `<%= raw "your database stored HTML string"%>`

In your case `<%= raw "<p> <strong>test</strong></p> <h3 style="color:blue;"> <strong>test 1</strong></h3>" %>`

Comment: cool thanks but it worked with wothout the quotes as i have got @page.description . but thanks :)